# Trying to render a component after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a simple signup>dashboard page in Reactjs with node and mongodb on the backend. Signup component structure is something like this:

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
import VendorDashboard from './../vendor_dashboard/VendorDashboard';
import {
  Route,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router';

class VendorRegistration extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      country: '',
      phone: '',
      email: '',
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const state = this.state;
    state[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(state)
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      city,
      state,
      country,
      phone,
      email,
      username,
      password
    } = this.state;
    axios.post('/vendor-registration/submitVendorSignup', {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        city,
        state,
        country,
        phone,
        email,
        username,
        password
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response); <
        Redirect to = "/vendor-dashboard" / >
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      city,
      state,
      country,
      phone,
      email,
      username,
      password
    } = this.state;
    return ( <
      div className = "wrapper" >
      <
      section className = "header" >
      <
      div className = "header-wrapper" >
      <
      nav >
      <
      div className = "container-fluid" >
      <
      div className = "navbar-header" >
      <
      button type = "button"
      className = "navbar-toggle"
      data - toggle = "collapse"
      data - target = "#myNavbar" >
      <
      span className = "icon-bar" > < /span> <
      span className = "icon-bar" > < /span> <
      span className = "icon-bar" > < /span> <
      /button> <
      /div> <
      div className = "collapse navbar-collapse"
      id = "myNavbar" >
      <
      ul className = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
      <
      li className = "dropdown" >

      <
      a className = "dropdown-toggle anchor-tag-color"
      data - toggle = "dropdown"
      href = "#" > Browse <
      span className = "caret" > < /span> <
      /a> <
      ul className = "dropdown-menu" >
      <
      li >
      <
      a className = "anchor-tag-color"
      href = "#" > t < /a> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      a className = "anchor-tag-color"
      href = "#" > Contact Us < /a> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      a className = "anchor-tag-color"
      href = "#" > Page 1 - 3 < /a> <
      /li> <
      /ul> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      a className = "anchor-tag-color"
      href = "#" > Contact Us < /a> <
      /li> <
      li className = "dropdown" >

      <
      a className = "dropdown-toggle anchor-tag-color"
      data - toggle = "dropdown"
      href = "#" >
      <
      div className = "position-image-profile" >

      <
      /div>
      My Account <
      span className = "caret" > < /span> <
      /a> <
      ul className = "dropdown-menu" >
      <
      li >
      <
      a className = "anchor-tag-color"
      href = "/login" > Login < /a> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      a className = "anchor-tag-color"
      href = "/" > Signup < /a> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      a className = "anchor-tag-color"
      href = "/vendor" > Signup As A Vendor < /a> <
      /li> <
      li > < a className = "anchor-tag-color"
      href = "/vendor-registration" > vendore registration < /a></li >
      <
      /ul> <
      /li> <
      /ul>

      <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /nav> <
      /div> <
      /section> <
      div className = "clearfix" > < /div> <
      section className = "banner-info" >
      <
      div className = "banner-wrapper" >
      <
      div className = "container" >
      <
      div className = "banner-content" >

      <
      div cuserslass = "clearfix" > < /div> <
      div className = "col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right" >
      <
      div className = "banner-signup-form-wrapper" >
      <
      div className = "banner-signup-form" >
      <
      h3 > Course Manager < /h3> <
      p > Manage Your college listing and more < /p>

      <
      form onSubmit = {
        this.handleSubmit
      } >
      <
      div className = "data-container" >
      <
      div className = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" >
      <
      select className = "form-control input-text required-entry" >
      <
      option > Title < /option> <
      option > Mr. < /option> <
      option > Mrs. < /option> <
      /select> <
      /div> <
      div className = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      id = "firstName"
      name = "firstName"
      value = {
        firstName
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      title = "First Name"
      maxLength = "255"
      className = "form-control input-text required-entry"
      placeholder = "First Name" / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      id = "lastName"
      name = "lastName"
      value = {
        lastName
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      title = "First Name"
      maxLength = "255"
      className = "form-control input-text required-entry"
      placeholder = "Last name" / >
      <
      /div>

      <
      /div> <
      div className = "data-container" >
      <
      div className = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      id = "city"
      name = "city"
      value = {
        city
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      title = "City"
      maxLength = "255"
      className = "form-control input-text required-entry"
      placeholder = "City" / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      id = "input-state"
      name = "state"
      value = {
        state
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      title = "State"
      maxLength = "255"
      className = "form-control input-text required-entry input-state"
      placeholder = "Type State" / >
      <
      span className = "state-placeholder" > State < /span>

      <
      /div> <
      div className = "col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" >
      <
      select className = "form-control input-text required-entry"
      name = "country"
      value = {
        country
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      } >
      <
      option > Country < /option> <
      option > India < /option> <
      option > Nepal < /option> <
      /select> <
      /div>

      <
      /div> <
      div className = "data-container" >
      <
      div className = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      id = "phone"
      name = "phone"
      value = {
        phone
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      title = "phone"
      maxLength = "255"
      className = "form-control input-text required-entry"
      placeholder = "Mobile No" / >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      id = "input-email"
      name = "email"
      value = {
        email
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      title = "email"
      maxLength = "255"
      className = "form-control input-text required-entry input-email"
      placeholder = "Type Your Email" / >
      <
      span className = "email-placeholder" > Email < /span> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      div className = "data-container" >
      <
      div className = "col-md-12" >
      <
      input type = "text"
      id = "input-username"
      name = "username"
      value = {
        username
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      title = "Username"
      maxLength = "255"
      className = "form-control input-text required-entry"
      placeholder = "Enter Username"
      autoComplete = "off" / >
      <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      div className = "data-container" >
      <
      div className = "col-md-12" >
      <
      input type = "password"
      id = "input-password"
      name = "password"
      value = {
        password
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      title = "Password"
      maxLength = "255"
      className = "form-control input-text required-entry"
      placeholder = "************"
      autoComplete = "off" / >
      <
      span className = "password-placeholder" > Password < /span> <
      /div>

      <
      /div>

      <
      div className = "data-container" >
      <
      div className = "col-md-6" >
      <
      input type = "checkbox" / > < span className = "terms-condition" > Agree to < a href = "#" > Terms and Conditon < /a></span >
      <
      /div> <
      div className = "col-md-6" >
      <
      input type = "submit"
      value = "Submit"
      className = "form-submit pull-right" / >
      <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /form>

      <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      div className = "clearfix" > < /div>

      <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /section> <
      div className = "clearfix" > < /div> <
      section className = "footer" >
      <
      div className = "footer-wrapper" >
      <
      div className = "container" >
      <
      div className = "col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-3" >
      <
      div className = "footer-logo" >
      <
      img src = "/images/logo-small.png" / >
      <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      div className = "col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-3 footer-menu" >
      <
      ul >
      <
      h4 > Information < /h4> <
      li > Private Policy < /li> <
      li > Terms and Condition < /li> <
      li > Faq < /li> <
      li > Contact Us < /li> <
      /ul> <
      /div> <
      div className = "col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-3 footer-menu" >
      <
      ul >
      <
      h4 > Information < /h4> <
      li > Private Policy < /li> <
      li > Terms and Condition < /li> <
      li > Faq < /li> <
      li > Contact Us < /li> <
      /ul> <
      /div> <
      div className = "col-md-2 col-xs-6 col-sm-3  footer-menu" >
      <
      ul >
      <
      h4 > Information < /h4> <
      li > Private Policy < /li> <
      li > Terms and Condition < /li> <
      li > Faq < /li> <
      li > Contact Us < /li> <
      /ul> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /section> <
      /div>
    )
  }
}


export default VendorRegistration;
```

As you can see, i tried using 'Redirect' but it didnt worked. Keep in mind that i am very new to React so i'm not very familiar to react routing/redirecting. Vendor dashboard component is defined in the Router

```js
< Route exact path = '/vendor-dashboard'
component = {
  VendorDashboard
}
/>
```

I want to render dashboard after signup is completed and response is recieved successfully. How can i accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of the route components history object like so:

```
 .then(response => {
    this.props.history.push("/vendor-dashboard")
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `ES6 arrow function`: try this

```
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response); <
    Redirect to = "/vendor-dashboard" / >
  })
```

Comment: Didnt worked. Still just recieving the response in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can used push function of history or visit this [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect/push-bool) for further techniques. It well explained React routing.